# account for whitespace in capturing group

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex to capture some AV data found in various payloads from Windows Defender.

The common string is:

```
TargetUser:
```

The problem is when trying to capture a username that contains a whitespace. My regex below only captures "NT" - See [test string](https://regex101.com/r/9WlGvE/1) on Regex101

```
TargetUser: "CONTOSO\JDoe" 
TargetUser: "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```

Regex:

```
TargetUser:\s+([^ ]+)
```

Comment: You are excluding a "blank", so why should it be captured at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `TargetUser:\s+"([^"]+)"`

`"([^"]+)"` : match `"` then capture everything till `"`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/0P4JBj/2)

---

If you want to capture the `"` too then move the `"` inside capturing group like

[`TargetUser:\s+("[^"]+")`](https://regex101.com/r/cBn8mG/1)

Comment: And add a final `"` if you need that `"([^"]+")`

Comment: FWIW, His original regex captures both quotes, yours does not.

Comment: @JohnHascall i actually think , `"` are not required , because java will give the string object directly but let me add it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your regex says "one or more spaces followed by one or more non spaces".  What are the valid characters that can appear in your user names?  Assume it is spaces, alphas, and numerics.  A regex for this would be [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+